# Permission denied: Cannot hide from Groups directory

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm trying to patch an existing group via the API but it's returning this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Permission denied: Cannot hide from Groups directory."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Permission denied: Cannot hide from Groups directory."
 }
}
```

The group currently has "showInGroupDirectory" => false.

I have set showInGroupDirectory to true in the patch request so I don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer.. and it's pretty obvious:

- You need to go to admin settings (https://admin.google.com/#your-domain).
- Then go to Apps -> Google Apps -> Groups for business -> Advanced Settings.
- Then tick this box: http://screencast.com/t/yKh7w5hB (Group owners can hide groups from the groups directory )